# Firestore- Querying Subcollections

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
firestore.collection("CATEGORIES").document("HOME").collection("TOP_DEALS")
                .orderBy("index").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Task Successful? "+task.isSuccessful());
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: task.getResult().getDocuments().size() :"+task.getResult().getDocuments().size());
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:task.getResult()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: inside For loop");
                    }
                }else {
                    String error=task.getException().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

I want to work with all the documents in the TOP_DEALS subcollection.
Even though the task is successful,task.result() is empty and statements within for each are never executed.
How should i query the all the documents in a subcollection?

Comment: Please don't put pictures of code - it's impossible for anyone to search for the same issue in the future.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: The same goes for all text.  Copy the text into the question itself so it's easy to read.

Comment: Please add a more detailed screenshot of your `TOP_DEALS` subcollection. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added detailed Screenshots of TOP_DEALS.

Comment: @ak21 does it work without `orderBy`?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on SO!

If I understand correctly `index` field is in field of `HOME` document. According to [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations):

> An orderBy() clause also filters for existence of the given fields.
>   The result set will not include documents that do not contain the
>   given fields.

In the provided code the 'orderBy' is used on `TOP_DEALS` collection, while the filed is in parent document `HOME`.

I am not sure what do you want to order here, but I think there 2 ways to solve. 1st you have to move `orderby` to `CATEGORIES` collection or 2nd to add index to documents in `TOP_DEALS` collection.

Comment: All the TOP_DEALS documents have a index field as well.